# On iOS, what makes libxml2 Public but libxslt Private?

Tags: ios

I've taken a look at a number of questions regarding using libxml2 and libxslt on iOS.  And the consensus seems to be that libxml2 is public and can be used without getting an app rejected from the Apple App Store.  And that the opposite is true of libxslt--using libxslt will get an app rejected.

But looking at the two libraries, I don't see how the two differ.  Both dylib's are available to be added to my project through XCode.  Both require that I add the path to the headers in project.  And I don't see any documentation for either on the iOS Dev Center.

Is there anything else I should be looking at to determine if a library is non-public?  Or is it just whatever Apple decides when they evaluate the app, and submitting it to the App Store is the only way to find out?

Answer (score 2):

I've continued to work on the app that requires the use of libxml2 and libxslt, and in the process, I think I've figured out what distinguishes the two libraries.  I was fooled by the presence of the header files for both libraries on my system.  But I didn't understand how XCode looks for system header files.  The key is that each SDK installed on my system has its own set of header files and XCode is set to automatically search for headers in the right location, the right location being dependent on the Base SDK I've set for my project.

Since I'm using the iOS 4.3 SDK, the system header files are located in:

/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/

When I look under that directory, I find the files for libxml2, but not the files for libxslt.  The fact that the libxslt header files are on my system in some other directory is just a red herring.  They aren't in the SDK and therefore shouldn't be used if I want to get the app approved by Apple for the App Store.

Here's some more info from Apple on the SDK configuration:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/48840

Security vulnerability in libxslt; as good of a reason as any.

It seems to be fixed in iOS 5 though so hopefully things may change.